# About Chen's theorem

Tags: number-theory

Chen's theorem says that every sufficiently large even number is a sum of two primes or a prime and a semiprime. Is it also true if we strictly take the prime in one of the addends to be those primes congruent to 1 mod 4 only?

***I found that if it also holds, there can only be finitely many primes of the form x^2 + 1.

Comment: It would be surprising becuase it is conjectured that $x^2+1$ is prime for infinite many $x$. And the evidence for this seems to be overhelming, although no proof is known. Please formulate exactly, which statement would imply that the number of primes of the form $x^2+1$ is finite.

Comment: I reviewed my result and I missed to include that there would only be finitely many primes of the form x^2 + 1 iff for suffiently large even N,  N=p+n where p is a prime congruent to 1 mod 4 and p divides 4n^2 + 1.

Comment: "$p$ divides $4n^2+1$" is a strong requirement. It cannot be expected that a representation of $N=p+n$ with that requirement exists for all sufficiently large even $N$.

Comment: Can you please show me a formal proof for that?